# setting an annual task on windows task scheduler

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

Is it possible to create a task in task scheduler that would execute only once a year?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This can be done using Monthly!**

[image]

Comment: +1 Good answer.  This will ensure that the task is run on the same day every year.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an option in the Task Scheduler to run a task annually or yearly; however, you may still be able to do this.

- In the Basic Task Wizard, select "Daily".  You should see the screen shown below.

[image: Enter number of days between recurrence of Task]

- In the "Recur every ___ days" field, enter 365.
- Continue entering the details for your task as normal.